# /etc/profile not sourced on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: java, configuration, etc

I am a newbie on ubuntu. I have used CentOS for several years but change to Ubuntu. I install ubuntu 20.10 desktop on virtual machine and oracle jdk and anaconda 2020-12 on it. And I set JAVA_HOME and PYTHON_HOME into /etc/profile like below,

```
############ JDK 11 PATH #############
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

######### PYTHON PATH ############
PYTHON_HOME=/usr/lib/python/anaconda3
export PATH=$PATH:$PYTHON_HOME/bin
```

When the ubuntu is started and logged into `root` user, java command is not found.

```
$ su
password:
# java -version
Command 'java' not found.
```

But, when `source /etc/profile` is executed on the shell manually, java command works. Even more I can not understand is `python --version` command works correctly without `source /etc/profile`. Python command is executed directly when logged into `root` user. Maybe these are some differences between centos and ubuntu. But I have no ideas how to solve this issue. Any reply will be welcome. Best regards

Comment: There is no version 20 do you mean 20.04 or 20.10?

Comment: version is 20.10. apology!

Comment: Ubuntu uses "dash", At the top of /etc/profile: "# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...)."

Comment: I am afraid I can not understand the comment.

Comment: /etc/profile is read for *login shells* - to invoke a login shell with su, you need to add the `-` or `-l`/`--login` option ex. `su -` in place of plain `su`